# Xdebug in Sublime Text 3: how to see the sub-array content in the Xdebug context

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublimetext3, xdebug

When I put a break point with Xdebug I can see the content of the current variables of the environment. Some of these variables are an array with another array inside. I don't know how to see the content of that sub-array:

[image: Screenshot of the sub-array I can't see]

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the following to the user configuration file of the Xdebug plugin (*Preferences > Package Settings > Xdebug > Settings - User*):

```
{
    "max_depth": 2
}
```

That's for one sub-array. If you want a sub-sub-array just type: `"max_depth": 3`...

Comment: Shouldn't one just set the value to a large number by default to save everyone's time?

Comment: Update: A large number would slow down the debugger. I found out that 3 is a good balance.

Comment: You may also want to increase "max_children" from 32 to something larger.